# Redirecting to a correct action after authentication interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, struts2, actionresult

I'm using Struts 2 and I have a private package of actions, because certain actions require login to be accessed. So I have this in my secure package:

```xml
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="com.koorde.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
        
    <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>    
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
    
<default-interceptor-ref name="secureStack"/>

<global-results>
    <result name="login" type="redirect">dologin</result>
    <result name="session_error" type="redirect"> html/error/hibernate_session.jsp</result>
    <result name="error" type="redirect"> html/error/hibernate_session.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

And of course other actions definition.

**My problem is the following:**

Let's say a user want to access his personal area. He clicks on `personalArea` link and he will be automatically redirected on login page (cause `personalArea` is a secure action). What I want is: after login user is automatically redirect (to continue the action) to `personalArea` and not home page.

So, what I want is: when user log in into the system because of a secure actions, after login the execution of the action (secured) continues.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to keep track of the user intercepting their URLs. You might do it in the authentication interceptor.

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
session.put("savedUrl", request.getRequestURI()+(queryString==null?"":("?"+queryString)));
```

use the global result with dynamic parameter

```
@Results({
  @Result(name = "return", type = "redirect", location = "${savedUrl}")
})
```

after login check the session for `savedUrl` and return result `"return"`. Assumed providing getter for the dynamic parameter.

Comment: I've got the first part. But where should I put this?

@Results({
  @Result(name = "return", type = "redirect", location = "${savedUrl}")
})

Comment: Okay I put that above the class definition (LoginAction) and I'm returning "return" (as string). But I've got

SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: No result defined for action com.koorde.action.LoginAction and result return
No result defined for action com.koorde.action.LoginAction and result return

Comment: If you don't like annotaton result, configure it in xml.

Comment: Yeah I'm using xml. My question is: how can I put this ${savedUrl} in xml?

Comment: <result name="return" type="redirect">${savedUrl}</result>

Comment: Mhh...it doesn't seem to work. I have no errors now. This is the struts.xml configuration for the login action:

 <action name="login" class="com.koorde.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="dispatcher">html/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="return" type="dispatcher">${savedUrl}</result>
            <result name="input">html/signupLogin.jsp</result>
        </action>

But return "return" redirect on index page

Comment: Also, why did you change the type of the result?

Comment: because the other way didn't work :)... sadly both ways don't work

Comment: I'm happy it helped you, but did you read the last sentence in my answer?

Comment: Assumed providing getter for the dynamic parameter?? Yeah I didn't quite realised that meant to create a class variable implementing the setter :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I was able to make it work. Basically what I missed from the solution proposed by Roman C. was that I need to have a class variable saved (so not only have it in the session).

private String savedUrl;

```
public String getSavedUrl(){
    return savedUrl;
}
```

That did the trick.

Thanks