# Redirect from login interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, authentication, struts2, interceptor, actionresult

Our application requires users to be logged in to view any content. Access to all pages is intercepted by `LoginInterceptor` which brings up the login form if there's no valid session for the user.

I'd like the interceptor to remember the original request URI before displaying the login form and redirect to it if the login form validation is successful.

I tried to follow [Struts 2 Redirect to correct action after authentication interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410407/struts-2-redirect-to-correct-action-after-authentication-interceptor).

```
@Service
@Results({
    @Result(name = "redirect", type = "redirect", location = "${savedUrl}")
})
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    //...
    private String savedUrl;
    //...
    @Override
    public final String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
       // ...
       savedUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("savedUrl");
       // ...
       if (processLogin(request, session)) { // validate login form
           if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(savedUrl)) {
              return "redirect";
           }
           return LOGIN_SUCCESS_RESULT;
       }
       // if there's no loginData in sesssion, remeber the URI and display a login form
       String queryString = request.getQueryString();
       session.setAttribute("savedUrl", request.getRequestURI() + (queryString==null ? "" : ("?" + queryString)));
       return "login";
    }
    // ...
    public String getSavedUrl(){
       return savedUrl;
    }
}
```

However I get a blank page as a result of `return "redirect"`.  `getSavedUrl()` is never called.

**Solution:**

Scratch the `@Results` annotation completely and instead of `return "redirect";` call

```
response.sendRedirect(savedUrl); return null;
```

Comment: Does your interceptor allow to browse unauthenticated?

Comment: No, it doesn't, if you are not logged in (no session), you are redirected to the login form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not logged in then redirect to `LOGIN` result. Then you should rewrite your interceptor something like

```
public final String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
   // before save original url
   Map session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
   Object action = invocation.getAction();
   if (!(action instanceof LoginAction)){ 
     String queryString = request.getQueryString();
     session.put("savedUrl", request.getRequestURI()+(queryString==null?"":("?"+queryString)));
   } else {
     return invocation.invoke();
   }

   if (!processLogin(request, session)) { //return false if not authenticated
     session.put("isLogin", true);
     return Action.LOGIN;
   } else {
       savedUrl = (String) session.get("savedUrl");
       boolean isLogin = (boolean)session.get("isLogin");
       if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(savedUrl) && isLogin) {
          session.put("isLogin", false); 
          return "redirect";
       }
       return invocation.invoke();
   }
}
```

Comment: What makes your return "redirect"; work? I don't see any difference to my old version.  I think the annotation is not right. A co-worker has found a solution that I added to my question.

Comment: `"redirect"` is a result and should be configured to the base action class or globally (that I mentioned in the link above) using xml configuration. If you don't see the difference may be use some diff tool?

Comment: I can't test/use your version without making a lot of changes in our classes and logic. It'd be more useful to point out why my original code failed. Edit: I think I got it... I'm accepting your answer.