# Handling a authentication scenario in struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am using struts2 (with Jquery plugin). What is the best way to implement this?

User clicks on an action  , the action class validates the request and finds the user is not authenticated(not logged in) and redirects him to login page with error code 401. User enters login details and sign-in. Now he should not be taken in to the my account page but to the previous action which was blocked due to 401.

I think it is require to save the request uri in some hidden field when 401 is sent to user and resubmit that uri along with current sign-in request?

Comment: See [Struts 2 - Redirecting to a correct action after authentication interceptor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18410407/573032), or [Struts2 redirect from login interceptor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20993574/573032).