# How to get struts2 action messages on to Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts-action

I have a login modal. The modal(bootstrap) form is a part of header.jsp which gets included in every JSP.
How do I get action error messages back to my modal if user enters wrong username/password?

Struts.xml

```xml
<action name="authenticate" method="login"
       class="app.resumerepo.in.action.LoginAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginCheck" />
    <result name="success" type="redirect">myaccount.action</result>
    <result name="input"> </result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/common/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

for the result "input" what I should mention so that I get action error messages on to Login modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure your `loginCheck` is an Interceptor Stack, and not a single Interceptor. In the latter case, create a custom Interceptor Stack with your `loginCheck` Interceptor inside, or declare both your Interceptor and the `defaultStack` like this:

   ```xml
   <action name="authenticate" method="login"
          class="app.resumerepo.in.action.LoginAction">
       <interceptor-ref name="loginCheck"   />
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       ...
   ```
2. In your code it is not shown how you landed on the login page; btw, to make it work as you are asking, just configure the `input` result to return the JSP page you are coming from, eg:

   ```xml
   <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
   ```

   Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238610/1654265) that may help.

Comment: Yes on the redirected JSP I am just calling the same login modal.It works now!!

Comment: Good, glad that helped. Any reason not to upvote (I see you have 0 votes cast, ever!..)

Comment: I need one more favor .. it is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621994/handling-a-authentication-scenario-in-struts2

Answer (score 0):

I am going to correct the interceptor part and
on login fail , I redirected to a login_error.jsp  where I am calling the same modal.
It works as expected.

```
                    <%@page session="false"%>
                    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
                    <%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                    <title>Insert title here</title>

                    </head>
                    <body style="background-color:#FFF;">
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
                       </script>

                    </body>
                    </html>
```